# Eloquent orderBy except one row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I basically just want to order my results by name except for 1 row - which I want to keep at the bottom of the results.

I have the following database table:

```
INSERT INTO `teams` (`id`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 'Anaheim Ducks', NULL, NULL),
(2, 'Arizona Coyotes', NULL, NULL),
(3, 'Atlanta Flames', NULL, NULL),
(4, 'Atlanta Thrashers', NULL, NULL),
(5, 'Boston Bruins', NULL, NULL),
(6, 'Buffalo Sabres', NULL, NULL),
(7, 'Calgary Flames', NULL, NULL),
(8, 'California Golden Seals', NULL, NULL),
(9, 'Carolina Hurricanes', NULL, NULL),
(10, 'Chicago Blackhawks', NULL, NULL),
(11, 'Cleveland Barons', NULL, NULL),
(12, 'Colorado Avalanche', NULL, NULL),
(13, 'Colorado Rockies', NULL, NULL),
(14, 'Columbus Blue Jackets', NULL, NULL),
(49, 'Other', NULL, NULL);
```

Now, I want to use Eloquent to order these all by `nam`e, EXCEPT I want `Other` to be at the bottom.

I am unsure how to do this using `orderBy()`. How do I do this?

Comment: For the examples you give, `order by name` will do just that.

Comment: There are other rows, I simply condensed my example so it wouldn't be a giant wall of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to @Anton's answer (and you're using Laravel 5.3+) you could make use of the [partition()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-partition) method:

```
$teams = Team::orderBy('name')->get()
    ->partition(function ($item) {
        return $item->name != 'Other';
    })->flatten();
```

This will push the "Other" row to the bottom of the list whilst keeping the rest of the collection in order.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own comparator for sorting and implement any logic you want.

For example:

```
Teams::all()->sort(function($a, $b) {
    if ($a->name === 'Other') return 1; // $a has lower priority, so move $a down
    if ($b->name === 'Other') return -1; // $b has lower priority, so move $b down
    return ($a->id > $b->id) ? 1 : -1; // default sort logic, you can compare any other fields
});
```